# Remove an attribute with XMLStarlet

Tags: xpath, xmlstarlet

I have an XML document and I'd like to use XMLStarlet to remove all attributes, along with their values, of a certain type from all elements (or all elements of a given type) without disturbing its other attributes.

For example, I want to remove all `bad` attributes from any `a` element:

```
<root>
  <a href="." bad="yes"/>
  <a bad=""/>
</root>
```

becomes

```
<root>
  <a href="."/>
  <a/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XMLStarlet's `ed` subcommand has a `--delete` or `-d` option.

Remove `bad` attribute from `a` elements:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//a/@bad' input.xml
```

Remove all `bad` attributes:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//@bad' input.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way to have `xmlstarlet` do this directly, but as far as I can see, you can invoke XSLT transformations:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@bad"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Apply the stylesheet with a command similar to (info taken from [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#d0e442)):

```
xml tr stylesheet.xsl input.xml
```

The resulting XML file:

```
<root>
  <a href="."/>
  <a/>
</root>
```

---

> from all elements (or all elements of a given type)

If you'd like to only remove the `bad` attribute from certain elements rather than all, use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element/@bad"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where "element" is the name of the element that should no longer carry the `bad` attribute.